# Pause macros if a cell changes value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a workbook with a very complicated set of macros (100's of them).  Somewhere, one of the macros sometimes changes the value in a specific cell, but I can't figure out which one.  If there a way to pause VBA execution if a particular cell is changed, so I can see which Sub changed it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

teylyn's answer is great; I'm using a similar premise, but without the need to update existing macros, basicaly forcing a run-time error when the cell being monitored is updated

This is the setup: VBA module for the cell monitored (in my case cell C3)

The _Change event triggers a division by 0 if Target is C3:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 3 And Target.Column = 3 Then Debug.Print 1 / 0
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    x1
End Sub
```

3 Test functions in a standard module, each updating Cells A3, B3, and C3:

```
Sub x1()
    Cells(3, 1) = Cells(3, 1) + 1
    x2
End Sub

Sub x2()
    Cells(3, 3) = Cells(3, 2) + 1
    x3
End Sub

Sub x3()
    Cells(3, 2) = Cells(3, 3) + 1
End Sub
```

---

When I change selection on the sheet the process starts and it displays an error window like this:

[image]

---

I click the Debug button and it takes me to the _Change event line with the error:

[image]

---

At this point I bring up the Call Stack (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)

This shows all calls made, the lastest one being at the top, so double-click the previous one:

[image]

---

The macro that updated the cell will have a green triangle ponting to the exact line that updated it

Comment: Nice approach. I like that!

Comment: Darn - I really liked the look of this approach, but it isn't working.  If I manually change the value in the cell (type in a new number) then it drops me into the debugger.  If I run the big master macro, though, it runs successfully.

Comment: Aha.  I figured this out.  The big macro sequence was being kicked off by changing a form control (non-ActiveX) comboBox.  The cell in question wasn't being changed by the macro - it was the direct target of the comboBox.  (This isn't quite as obvious as it sounds, because the changed cell is numeric and completely unused, while the comboBox presents text options)   Apparently, changing the value of a cell via comboBox does not trigger a worksheet_change event.  Your suggestion did help me rule other things out, though, and would be really handy if I had the problem I thought I had!

Comment: I'm glad you eventually figured it out :) nice work !

Comment: Very cool........very neat.........very, very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Let each macro debug.print its name when it starts. Then create a Worksheet Change event that monitors the specific cell. Let the change event pop up a message. Go to the Immediate window and see what macro was started before the message box appeared.

[image]

Comment: +1 This would work nicely if there were not sooo many subroutines in my macro sequence.  Literally hundreds.  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Thanks. Even though this setup requires more upfront effort it's more flexible and can be configured to provide more useful info, for the long run